# Wordpress Woocommerce find order ID from refund ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up some API connectivity between our woocommerce webshop and our finance software using a third party piece of software. There are some problems with it and they send me back the refund ID's from woocommerce. They don't have the order ID's associated with the refund ID but they need them.

I tried to download the complete database and search in it but I just cannot find any reference of the refund ID in the database.

The only thing that I need is some way of finding the order ID from using the refund ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$refund = new WC_Order_Refund( $refund_id );

$refund->get_parent_id();
```

Try this code